# How to combine objects of arrays that are in different objects

Tags: javascript

```js
const all = [{
  'name': 'first',
  'attributes': [{
    'name': 'attr1'
  }]
}, {
  'name': 'second',
  'attributes': [{
    'name': 'attr2'
  }]
}]


const res = all.reduce((acc, el) => {
  return acc + el.attributes
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

I need get next

```
result => [{'name':'attr1'}, {'name':'attr2'}]
```

What is the best way do it, it can be not only reduce.

Comment: Why not just map?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because that would return an Array of Arrays. `flatMap`, though, would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.concat()` method to concatenate arrays, not `+`.

```js
const all = [{
  'name': 'first',
  'attributes': [{
    'name': 'attr1'
  }]
}, {
  'name': 'second',
  'attributes': [{
    'name': 'attr2'
  }]
}]


const res = all.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat(el.attributes), [])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use spread operator for readability:

`[...acc, ...el.attributes]` means that it is a new array, in the beginning of which are all `acc` elements are placed, and after all `el.attributes` elements are placed.

The arrow function in `reduce` has no curly braces and the return keyword, in this form it returns `[...acc, ...el.attributes]`:

```js
const all = [{
  'name': 'first',
  'attributes': [{
    'name': 'attr1'
  }]
}, {
  'name': 'second',
  'attributes': [{
    'name': 'attr2'
  }]
}]

  
const res = all.reduce((acc, el) => [...acc, ...el.attributes], [])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const all = [{ name: 'first', attributes: [{ name: 'attr1' }] }, { name: 'second', attributes: [{ name: 'attr2' }] }];

const res = all.flatMap(x => x.attributes);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

One line code for you

```
[].concat(...all.map(item => item.attributes ))
```